# How to stack mp3 files in listbox

Tags: vb.net, multimedia

i'm trying to make a music player using AxWindowsMediaPlayer but i have a small problem on this import code. (the imported items go to a listbox @listbox1)

```
Public Class Form1
Dim song As String()
Dim directory As String()
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
            song = OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileNames
            directory = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            For items As Integer = 0 To song.Count - 1
                ListBox1.Items.Add(song(items))
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
Try
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = directory(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
End Sub
End Class
Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

But when trying to re-import new songs (after the first import) and trying to play it, the newly reimported songs overwrites the previous ones (e.g. oldimportedsong1 gets overwritten by newimportedsong1, oldimportedsong2 gets overwritten by newimportedsong2)

Please help me out!

Comment: What does` i can't click on the items anymore`.  Looks like there is some sort of global variqable there, so of course you debugged your code right?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: revised my question if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will simplify your code if you use List(Of T). Otherwise you will have to ReDim Preserve your arrays.
What is happening in your code is you are overwritting your arrays every time you click the button.

```
Private song As New List(Of String)
Private directory As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Try
            If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                song.AddRange(OpenFileDialog1.SafeFileNames)
                directory.AddRange(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
                ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
                ListBox1.DataSource = song
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'empty catch boxes are the devil's workshop
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim i As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Dim path As String = directory(i)
End Sub
```